# How to mount RBD image (ceph) to default data directory of mysql docker

Tags: mysql, docker, ceph

I want mysql read/write data to my RBD image. I use rbd-docker-plugin to mount RBD into docker pull from https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

First I try

`docker run -it --volume-driver=rbd --volume foo:/mnt/foo ceph/base bash`

and I touch "aa" file inside /mnt/foo in docker then I stop docker and when I mount `foo` into another docker "aa" file still exist

---

Then I add my code into this [Docker file](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/5836bc9af9deb67b68c32bebad09a0f7513da36e/5.7/Dockerfile)

```
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/foo/mysql
RUN sed -i -e 's/\/var\/lib\/mysql/\/mnt\/foo\/mysql/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
VOLUME /mnt/foo/mysql
```

and build, run docker from this new Dockerfile

```
docker run -it --volume-driver=rbd --volume storage2/foo:/mnt/foo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password [image_id]
```

when I exec container I can use mysql and I see data of mysql (and "aa" file) in /mnt/foo/mysql, But when I stop docker and mount foo into another docker I can't see anything about mysql (but I still see "aa" file)

---

Finally I try

```
docker run --name some-mysql --volume-driver=rbd --volume foo:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql
```

but it error

> [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table
>   'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that there are no mysql files for mysql to read.

The problem is that you are mounting the partition after the installation of mysql so the partition will be empty.

Solution: start mysql with --initialize or --initialize-insecure

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html